# Sliding window of 50% overlap with a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sliding-window

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
              x   y   z
timestamp
some_date_1   5   2   4
some_date_2   1   2   6
some_date_3   7   3   5
 ...
some_date_50  4   3   6
```

and I want to apply a sliding window of size 10 (call this a variable `window_size`) with a 50% overlap (make this a variable `step_size` that's half of `window_size`) on the `x`, `y`, and `z` columns. Therefore, I would print the first 10 rows from 0 - 9. Afterwards, I would print 5 - 14, 10 - 19, 15 - 24, etc.

How would I do that if I had a function:

```
def sliding_window(df, window_size, step_size):
```

Assume `timestamp` is datetime.

I want to have separate structures for each window. So, for example, I want to have a separate DataFrame for the first ten rows, and then another for the next ten etc.

For simplicity, I will show an example with window size 4 and step size of 2.

```
                  x   y   z
timestamp
some_date_1   5   2   4
some_date_2   1   2   6
some_date_3   2   3   1
some_date_4   5   4   4

                 x   y   z
timestamp
some_date_3   2   3   1
some_date_4   5   4   4
some_date_5   6   7   9
some_date_6   2   1   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 73).reshape(-1, 3), columns=list('xyz'))
df
```

---

```
def windows(d, w, t):
    r = np.arange(len(d))
    s = r[::t]
    z = list(zip(s, s + w))
    f = '{0[0]}:{0[1]}'.format
    g = lambda t: d.iloc[t[0]:t[1]]
    return pd.concat(map(g, z), keys=map(f, z))
```

This returns a dataframe with a `pd.MultiIndex` and we can easily access each window with `loc`

```
wdf = windows(df, 10, 5)

wdf.loc['0:10']

    x   y   z
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
4  13  14  15
5  16  17  18
6  19  20  21
7  22  23  24
8  25  26  27
9  28  29  30
```

Or

```
wdf.loc['15:25']

     x   y   z
15  46  47  48
16  49  50  51
17  52  53  54
18  55  56  57
19  58  59  60
20  61  62  63
21  64  65  66
22  67  68  69
23  70  71  72
```

Comment: I edited my question as this isn't really what I was looking for.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 can you show me what your looking for?  Otherwise, I'm just guessing.

Comment: I gave an example

Comment: @dirtysocks45 then you can use the structure I provided and access each window with `loc` as I've specified.  If you don't like the way in which I've accessed each window, then show me how you'd like to access them.  Otherwise, this satisfies all requirements you've laid out.

Comment: Is there a way I can access them iteratively? I would like to pass in this function to another one which performs calculations on each window.

Comment: Yes.  You see the `map(g, z)` in the `windows` function?  That's the iterator you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150762/discussion-between-dirtysocks45-and-pirsquared).